# XML Twig insert processing instruction before matched tag in XML file

Tags: xml, perl

I have an xml document that contains a number of tags. I would like to replace one of these tags with a processing instruction of the form:

```
<?merge  subdocs = 0 :sheet1-01.xml?>.
```

However if  use the code:

```
$nodes[0]->insert_new_elt('before',=>'<?merge  subdocs = 0 :sheet1-01.xml?>')
```

where the tag I want to replace is contained within the variable $nodes[0] the result in the xml file is:

```
 <<?merge  subdocs = 0 :sheet1-01.xml?>/>
```

Which is clearly not what I want! I have searched the help pages of XML Twig and have found references to processing tags but cannot work out how to insert them in my xml document! Is it possible with XML Twig and if so how?

P.S. Forgot to mention that I am currently loading the entire XML file into memory and not using twig handlers.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<` and `>` from  `<?merge  subdocs = 0 :sheet1-01.xml?>` it appears that XML::Twig adds them for you.

**Edit**

Modify your `insert_new_elt` call to this

```
$nodes[0]->insert_new_elt('before', '#PI' =>'merge  subdocs = 0 :sheet1-01.xml')
```

I think this should work as you want

Comment: Almost! Now I get `<?merge  subdocs = 0 :sheet1-01.xml?/>` so the ending `/` is the problem now which makes sense as elements have an ending `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!! To do what I want I used the following code:

```
$nodes[0]->insert_new_elt( before => '#PI', 'merge  subdocs = 0 :sheet1-01.xml');
```

which inserts

```
<?merge  subdocs = 0 :sheet1-01.xml?>
```

as a processing instruction in the correct location